# How to get nested attributes using active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I using **active_model_serializers** gem, and I need to get nested attributes of **Service** model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title

  has_many   :subcategories,      serializer: SubcategorySerializer
end

class SubcategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title

  has_many   :services,      serializer: SubcategorySerializer
end

class ServiceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end
```

Category Controller:

```
class CategoriesController < BaseController
  def index
    categories = Category.all

    render json: categories, each_serializer: CategorySerializer
  end
end
```

Category serializers don't return nested attributes of **Service** model.

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category 1",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Sub category 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Sub category 2"
            }
    ]
  }
```

I need to get json result with nested Service model in subcategory
I using **active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.2)** 
How do that?

Comment: In `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb` file add
`ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**' `

Comment: Emy Thanks a lot! It's help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb` file add `ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**'`